# Как вывести из MySQL значение в таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql

Я сделал запрос к базе, получил массив значений, которые мне нужны, теперь хочу, чтобы мои значения были строками и при этом каждая в своей ячейке.
Вот код:

```
function id($data){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = '';
    $db_name = 'workers';
    $link=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $query = "SELECT id FROM workers WHERE id>0  ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die( mysqli_error($link));
    for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);
  return $data;
}
function output_id($arr){
        var_dump((id($arr)));
}
output_id($arr);
```

Comment: Ребят, сори, там не foreach должен быть, а return $data

Comment: Строки то в таблице HTML должны быть? Почему кстати используете for для получения массива? Логичнее же использовать while? Ну или вообще $data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); - тогда никаких циклов не нужно.

Comment: Да, в HTML, понял, спасибо большое, попробую ваш вариант

Comment: А вы собрались в каждой своей функции данные для коннекта прописывать?

Comment: Нет, я по другому сделал, все получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен вывод в таблицу HTML, то можно так:

```
function id($data){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = '';
    $db_name = 'workers';
    $link=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $query = "SELECT id FROM workers WHERE id>0  ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die( mysqli_error($link));
    $table = "<table>";
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $table = ."<tr><td>{$data['id']}</td></tr>";
    }
    $table = ."/<table>";
  return $table;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вам, большое за помощь!